# Adobe Acrobat and Illustrator - Print to 4 by 4 on A4 with 0 margin

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics, print-to-pdf

I bascially have a PDF of 16 pages.
I want to put them into 4 by 4 grid on a new A4 paper (in PDF).

I saw this "art board" thing in illustrator
[image]

This presentation/layout is EXACTLY what I want. Boarders with ZERO margin. But it is not the acutal product. When I save it, "art board" in Illustrator acutally means I have 16 pages. So it is a PDF with 16 pages, not what I want.

If I use Acrobat to print it to PDF.
It has GAPS and the margin is not 0.

[image]

I don't want to use Word to process it as PICTURES, I want to keep them in Vector form (ps,pdf,eps).
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have InDesign? If yes, you can place either the PDF or AI files exactly how you want them and print from there.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I have no experience in ID. But I might look at it. What kind of terms should I search for this "grid"?

Comment: Look into placing multi-page PDFs in InDesign. once an image is placed, you can resize and position it wherever you want on the page.